# Alternative to appregnew.aspx using SharePoint Online Powershell

Tags: office365, sharepoint-online

As per the Microsoft SharePoint Online documentation, for the provider hosted app the way to register an app is to visit https://.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/appregnew.aspx and generate application information like ClientID, ClientSecret etc.

My requirement is to find a SharePoint Online PowerShell way to perform the same.

I referred to the set of CmdLets for SharePoint Online at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161364%28v=office.15%29.aspx but unable to find the right CmdLet (not sure if that is available).

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

So we have used get-msolservicePrincipal to view the registration and remove-msolserviceprincipal to remove it so surely new-msolserviceprincipal would add a new one right? But it did not work. Well we also know that using the below three lines creates a new secondary certificate for certificate renewal

```
New-MsolServicePrincipalCredential -AppPrincipalId $clientId -Type Symmetric -Usage Sign -Value $newClientSecret
New-MsolServicePrincipalCredential -AppPrincipalId $clientId -Type Symmetric -Usage Verify -Value $newClientSecret
New-MsolServicePrincipalCredential -AppPrincipalId $clientId -Type Password -Usage Verify -Value $newClientSecret
```

Well what if we put those after we do the new-msolserviceprincipal? IT WORKS!

AppRegNew.aspx Alternative

```
$servicePrincipalName = @("$clientID/$appDomain")

Write-Output "Adding New app registration"
New-MsolServicePrincipal -ServicePrincipalNames $servicePrincipalName -AppPrincipalId $clientID -DisplayName $appName -Type Symmetric -Usage Verify -StartDate "02/23/2016" -EndDate "02/22/2017" -Addresses (New-MsolServicePrincipalAddresses -Address $appUrl) 
New-MsolServicePrincipalCredential -AppPrincipalId $clientId -Type Symmetric -Usage Sign -Value $newClientSecret
New-MsolServicePrincipalCredential -AppPrincipalId $clientId -Type Symmetric -Usage Verify -Value $newClientSecret
New-MsolServicePrincipalCredential -AppPrincipalId $clientId -Type Password -Usage Verify -Value $newClientSecret
```